# Regex to extract information from wp-config file

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, backup

I want to create a script to backup all my Wordpress installations without having to mark all the directories.

I want to test for the existence of the file wp-config.php and create a database backup with the information in this file.

Here my script which always outputs "nothing found":

```
$content = file_get_contents($sub_dir . '/wp-config.php');
if (preg_match_all("/define\('DB_NAME', '(.*?)'\)/", preg_quote($content, '/'), $result)) {
  print_r($result);
} 
else
  print "nothing found\n";
```

I want to do the same parsing with `DB_USER`, `DB_PASSWORD`, and `DB_HOST`.

Here's an example of the content in this config file:

```
../...

// ** Réglages MySQL - Votre hébergeur doit vous fournir ces informations. ** //
/** Nom de la base de données de WordPress. */
define('DB_NAME', 'thedbname');

/** Utilisateur de la base de données MySQL. */
define('DB_USER', 'thedbuser');

/** Mot de passe de la base de données MySQL. */
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'thedbpassword');

/** Adresse de l'hébergement MySQL. */
define('DB_HOST', 'thedbhost');

../...
```

Comment: Why do you use preg_quote? Remove it and your regex is fine.

Comment: @KrzysztofDuszczyk, I was using this script without preg_quote without success first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

The function [`preg_quote()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) escapes regex special characters, including `(` and `)`, so your subject string doesn't contain

```
define('DB_NAME', 'thedbname');
```

Instead, it contains

```
define\('DB_NAME', 'thedbname'\);
```

and your regex fails.

## Solution

Just remove the `preg_quote()` from your code, like this:

```
if (preg_match_all("/define\('DB_NAME', '(.*?)'\)/", $content, $result)) {
  print_r($result);
} else { // note: I added braces; it's better to use them always.
  print "nothing found\n";
}
```

This works correctly and outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => define('DB_NAME', 'thedbname')
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => thedbname
        )

)
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/NgNsp8).

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://rokaweb.ir/read-wpconfig-php/) is a function to read all WP DB defines:

```
function get_wordpress_data() {
    $content = @file_get_contents( '../wp-config.php' );

    if( ! $content ) {
        return false;
    }

    $params = [
        'db_name' => "/define.+?'DB_NAME'.+?'(.*?)'.+/",
        'db_user' => "/define.+?'DB_USER'.+?'(.*?)'.+/",
        'db_password' => "/define.+?'DB_PASSWORD'.+?'(.*?)'.+/",
        'db_host' => "/define.+?'DB_HOST'.+?'(.*?)'.+/",
    ];

    $return = [];

    foreach( $params as $key => $value ) {

        $found = preg_match_all( $value, $content, $result );

        if( $found ) {
            $return[ $key ] = $result[ 1 ][ 0 ];
        } else {
            $return[ $key ] = false;
        }

    }

    return $return;
}
```

this returns an array like this:

```
array (size=4)
  'db_name' => string '.........'
  'db_user' => string '.........'
  'db_password' => string '.........'
  'db_host' => string 'localhost'
```